# Nginx выдаёт 404

Tags: nginx, lua

```
location / {
        set $proxy "";
        root html;
        default_type text/html;
        rewrite_by_lua_block{ 
            local template = require "resty.template"
            local inspect = require("resty.inspect")
            local httpc = require("resty.http").new()
            local cjson = require "cjson"
            local ip = ngx.var.remote_addr
            

            local rr=ngx.var.request_uri;

            if rr == "/admin" then
                ngx.var.proxy = "ip:port"
            end   

        }
         proxy_pass http://$proxy$uri$is_args$args;
    }
```

Вышеуказанный код выдаёт 404, если отправить get запрос "/admin" с помощью ссылки, НО работает если просто поставить ngx.var.proxy = "ip:port", без условия (условие очевидно выполняется). Что не так?

Код на Openresty

Comment: зачем нужен этот программизм? нужно написать `location /admin {...}`

Comment: @nörbörnën зачем нужен этот бесполезный ответ? Нужно написать ответ на вопрос, который я задал, а не тот что ты придумал.

Comment: ну, попробую объяснить вам свой бесполезный ответ на первом комментарии вот к этому вопросу https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1493313/2659#comment2676925_1493313